# Finding a particular integral basis of the cyclotomic field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\zeta_{39}$ be a primitive $39$th root of unity.
How can I prove that all the conjugates of $\zeta_{39}$ form an integral basis
of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{39})$?

This is from the paper "Cyclotomic Construction of Leech's Lattice"
by M. Craig. It's supposed to follow from the identity
$$
\frac{ \theta^{3j} (\theta^{39}-1) }{\theta^{13} - 1} = 0 = \frac{ \theta^{} (\theta^{39}-1) }{\theta^{3} - 1},
$$
where $\theta = \zeta_{39}$ and $j \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thanks!